# how to get result form mysql query in specific ids

Tags: mysql

I have table call `Category`.

[image: Table]

if I use

```
query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM category WHERE id='$id'");
$result = $query->result_array();
return $result;
```

this will load all result.(`Id 1` to `id 12`)

Question is: I want to get ID which are grater than `id 10`.

I expect after query i need only `id 11` and `id 12` to be load.(id will be keep adding).

So how can i do that in CodeIgnitor with php??

Comment: So you are basically asking that you get all the records, but 11 as the first one?

Comment: @Blaatpraat ya. exactly right

Comment: WHERE id>10 is that what you're asking for ?

Comment: is your id column `int`? I take it it is.

Comment: *Yeah, duh*, what was I thinking? lol

Comment: What do you mean? You have a `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use :

```
$this->db->get_where('product', 'category_id >=10');
```

OR

```
$this->db->where('category_id  >=10');
```

Answer (score 7):

Change your query to say you want an id greater than the number you're looking for -

```
 "SELECT * FROM category WHERE id > '10'"
```

Answer (score 1):

using CodeIgniter standard:-

```
$this->db->select('*');

$this->db->from('category');

$this->db->where('id >', '10');

$query = $this->db->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a lot more with your query, like limitations.
I refer you to [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-where-clause.htm), for WHERE statements.

The query you want, it the following:

```
SELECT * FROM `category` WHERE `id` > 10
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use **WHERE** condition with **id > '10'**

```
 query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM category WHERE id > '10'");
```

Answer (score 0):

How about adding a WHERE clause to the query?

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM product WHERE category_id='$id' AND id > 10");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM category WHERE id>'10'");
 $result = $query->result_array();
 return $result;
```